# Wordpress Multiple DB Rows Into Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve the data of multiple product meta values for the same product but instead of displaying it in multiple rows I want the meta values as their own columns.

I start with:

```
   SELECT a.post_title, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
   FROM wp_posts a
   INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b
   ON a.ID = b.post_id
   WHERE a.post_type = 'product' 
   AND b.meta_key = '_custom_animal_id' 
   OR b.meta_key = '_custom_breed';
```

This returns a table:

| Name | meta_key | meta_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cow 1 | _custom_animal_id | FR4380 |
| Cow 1 | _custom_breed | HO |
| Cow 2 | _custom_animal_id | FR0001 |
| Cow 2 | _custom_breed | HO |
| Cow 3 | _custom_animal_id | FR9999 |
| Cow 3 | _custom_breed | ZZ |

What I want to display is:

| Name | Animal ID | Breed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cow 1 | FR4380 | HO |
| Cow 2 | FR0001 | HO |
| Cow 3 | FR9999 | ZZ |

I know I will need to group by post_id (as a the title may not be unique) but returning the rows to columns I have searched a lot and not finding the answer to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the condition aggregate function.

`MAX` with `CASE WHEN` to make the pivot

```
SELECT a.post_title 'Name', 
       MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = '_custom_animal_id' THEN b.meta_value END) 'Animal ID' , 
       MAX(CASE WHEN b.meta_key = '_custom_breed' THEN b.meta_value END) 'Breed'
FROM wp_posts a
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta b
ON a.ID = b.post_id
WHERE a.post_type = 'product' 
AND b.meta_key = '_custom_animal_id' 
OR b.meta_key = '_custom_breed'
GROUP BY a.post_title
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3adacd/1/0)**:

```
|  Name | Animal ID | Breed |
|-------|-----------|-------|
| Cow 1 |    FR4380 |    HO |
| Cow 2 |    FR0001 |    HO |
| Cow 3 |    FR9999 |    ZZ |
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to make use of a subquery here to get what we need. Make sure you have an appropriate index on wp_postmeta.meta_key if you haven't already.

```
SELECT a.post_title, animalid.meta_key, breed.meta_key
FROM wp_posts a
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_key
            FROM wp_postmeta
            WHERE meta_key = '_custom_animal_id') animalid ON a.ID = animalid.post_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, meta_key
            FROM wp_postmeta
            WHERE meta_key = '_custom_breed') breed ON a.ID = breed.post_id
WHERE a.post_type = 'product';
```

Comment: I need custom animal ID as you can see in the column in the 2nd table.

Comment: Oh I see, give me a moment to revise my query